# Will switching branches while running mvn clean install affect maven?

Tags: git, maven

I have a maven project that has several modules. Running mvn clean install takes more than one hour, so I want to switch to a different branch and work on some other task in the same project.

If I run mvn clean install on branch A and then switch to branch B which branch will maven use?

Comment: If your repo has a working tree (and if that is what maven uses) then maven will use whatever branch is checked out.

Comment: Yes. Switching branches can, and probably will, affect the files Maven is processing. The bigger issue here sounds like your Maven build taking over an hour...

Comment: What takes so long? How many modules do you have ? What kind of machine are you running this build on? Running Tests? Yes how many? How long took it to run them ? Apart from that you should stat using a CI solution like Jenkins to run such builds..

Comment: Thank you for your suggestions, but unfortunately, the project architecture is way out of my scope.

Comment: Maven has no idea that git is underneath, and considers the files  on disk.  You can check out another copy elsewhere, and work on that

Comment: Also "mvn clean install" sounds like some tests are not unit tests but integration tests, and you may consider moving them into a separate module away from your main sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maven will build the modules in dependency-order so if it has not yet built, say, Modules `C` and `D` when you switch branch then it will build the 'switched' versions of those modules rather than the versions of those modules as they were when you invoked `mvn clean install`.

I suspect it's safer for you to create a separate workspace, clone your repo to that workspace and then work on that workspace while the 'other' workspace is being built.

Of course, this ...

> Running mvn clean install takes more than one hour,

... sounds some warning bells but I'm assuming you are already aware of and (perhaps) addressing that issue separately.